# Updating and deleting the MySQLite database through dynamic button on QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, mysql-python

I have created a fairly simple app that takes three input parameter from the LineEdit's and displays it in the QTablewidget through the Button placed side it. In QTableWidget dynamic **update button** and **removes button** are created as the rows values are filled. Whenever QTableWidget's cell is changed and the update button is clicked, It updated the value in the database. Removes button helps to remove the specific row entry from the database.I am able to remove from value from QTableWidget but not from database.

```
ui,_ = loadUiType('drake.ui')
from db_new import DatabaseNew
db_new = DatabaseNew('database-punk-2')
class LoginNew(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show_database()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addToTableWidget)
    

    def addToTableWidget(self):
        self.row_data = []
        self.val1 =  self.lineEdit.text()
        self.row_data.append(self.val1)
        self.val2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.row_data.append(self.val2)
        self.val3 =  self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.row_data.append(self.val3)


        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(row+1)
        col = 0
        for item in self.row_data:
            cell = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, cell)
            col += 1
        
        db_new.insert(self.val1,self.val2, self.val3)
       
        for index in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            self.btx =  QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
            self.btn =  QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
            self.btx.setText("Update")
            self.btn.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("delete.png")))
            self.btn.setIconSize(QSize(35,35))
            self.btx.clicked.connect(self.update_pos)
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_pos)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(index,3, self.btx)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(index,4,self.btn)
        
    
    def show_database(self):
        res = db_new.fetch_data()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number,  QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

    def update_pos(self):
        self.button =self.focusWidget()
        self.index = self.tableWidget.indexAt(self.button.pos())
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btn_trigger)
    
    def btn_trigger(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Update Data", f' Value  is {self.index.row()} {self.index.column()}')
        # db_new.update(self.index.row()-1,self.val1,self.val2,self.val3)
        # Unable to find appropiate method for updating the values from the database.



        
    
    def delete_pos(self):
        rows = set()
        print("First row Value ")
        print(rows)
        for indexes in self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes():
            rows.add(indexes.row())
           

        for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True):
            self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)
        # Unable to find the appropiate logic for removing from database


def main():
    app =  QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = LoginNew()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Database File
[image]

UI file image
[image]

I am unable to update the database or delete a specific row using the row-delete button, I a'm unable to do it.

Comment: please provide a [mre], please no code pictures

Comment: what exactly is working unexpectedly? Are the correct functions called? From what I am seeing, you are only calling show_database() once during init and never again, hence no update...?

Comment: @ChristianKarcher I am not able to update the database because I didn't find how to sync the rowid of QTableWidget and id's of the database(Primary Key).

Answer (score 1):

From what I am seeing I understand the following:

With `show_database() -> fetch_data()` you are only getting the fields description_one, description_two, and status from your database.

The information which is lacking here is "ID". This field is required by your remove and update functions. You try to emulate this with `self.index.row()-1`, however this is bound to fail as IDs are typically auto-incrementing and hence not necessarily in a 1-2-3-fashion anymore.

So I would suggest adding an ID-column to the table, and getting this field with fetch_data as well. Once you have that, you should be able to use your remove and update functions in a straight forward way, directly implementing the fetched ID.

If you wand to declutter the interface, you can [hide this column](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableView.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableView.setColumnHidden), as it does not contain any viable information for a potential user of the interface.